# how do I call a variable in a controler from a model?

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

I have a model that must gather information from a table with company info.
data like company name, adress etc.
so I can use for example the company name to put in a footer an to put that name in invoices.

this is my model:

```
<?php

class Company extends CI_Model
{
public $name = '';
public $adress = '';

function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
}

function get_info() {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM company');

    foreach ($query->result() as $row ) {
        $this->name = $row->name;
        $this->adress = $row->adress;
    }
}
```

}

my controler looks like this:

```
    public function test() {
    $this->load->model('Company');
    $this->Bedrijf->get_info();
    echo $this->bedrijf->name;

}
```

when I open my test site I get a error:

> Undefined property: testproject::$name

what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
  function get_info() {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM company');

        foreach ($query->result() as $row ) {
            $data['name'] = $row->name;
            $data['adress'] = $row->adress;
        }
       return $data;
    }
```

my controler looks like this:

```
    public function test() {
    $this->load->model('company');
    $company_info = $this->company->get_info();
    echo $company_info['name'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not loading correctly you model. See how you can load your model in controller. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#loading

Try with this.

```
public function test() {
    $this->load->model('Company', 'Bedrijf');
    $this->Bedrijf->get_info();
    echo $this->Bedrijf->name;

}


// You are not defining assigning the different object here 
// from that you are calling i.e. $this->Bedrijf->get_info();
$this->load->model('Company');
$this->Bedrijf->get_info();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  public function test() {
        $obj_model = $this->load->model('Company');
        $Bedrijf->get_info();
        echo $Bedrijf->name;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

**model**

```
function get_info() {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM company');
    return $query->result();
}
```

**controller**

```
public function test() {
    $this->load->model('Company');
    $obj = $this->Company->get_info();
    echo $obj->name;
}
```